# jQuery: hidden divs need to re-appear

Tags: jquery, timeout, hide, show

I have a couple of products lined up next to each other in a div and i'm using this script to hide the one by one.

At some point they have all disappeared and I would like to have them all re-appear. I've tried some .show's but i might be wrong with the placement.

Can someone please have a look and see what needs to be done to get the script working as intended?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready (function() {
        "$('.add1').each(function(index) {
            setTimeout(function(el) {
                el.hide('slow');
            }, index * 2000, $(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want them to re-appear? `$('.add1').show()` will do it, but if there are still outstanding timeouts they'll hide some of the elements again. (Note also that passing that third parameter to `setTimeout()` won't work in all browsers.) As an aside, do you think the `echo` thing was really the best way to present JS code for this question?

Comment: I tried `$('.add1').show()` but it makes the `.add1` dissapear and appear right after it has dissapeared turning several `.add1` divs into a big dis- and re-appearing mess. I need them to re-appear after all `.add1` divs haves dis-appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    var $add1 = $('.add1').each(function(index, el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).hide('slow');
        }, index * 2000);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $add1.show('slow');
    }, $add1.length * 2000);
});
```

That is, first queue up all the timeouts to hide the elements, then queue up another timeout to show them again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tsuQd/

Of course, that shows them all at once. To show them one at a time you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    var $add1 = $('.add1'),
        count = $add1.length;        
    $add1.each(function(index, el) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).hide('slow');
        }, index * 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).show('slow');
        }, (count + index) * 2000);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tsuQd/1/

Note that I've tweaked the way that you were getting a reference to the element inside the timeout callbacks, because using a third parameter with `setTimeout()` doesn't work in all browsers.